# Why multiple threads using too much memory when holding Mutex

Tags: rust

Below code uses ~150MB in single thread but uses several GBs in 100 threads:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let f = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Foo::new("hello")));

    let mut threads = vec![];
    for i in 0..100 {
        let f = f.clone();
        let t = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let mut locked = f.lock().unwrap();
            *locked = Foo::new("hello");
            drop(locked);
            println!("{} reloaded", i);
            thread::yield_now();
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }

    threads.into_iter().for_each(|h| h.join().unwrap());
}

pub struct Foo {
    _data: Vec<String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(s: &str) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            _data: vec![s.to_owned(); 1024 * 1024],
        }
    }
}
```

While holding the `LockGuard`, a thread should have exclusive access. So, new `Foo` should be allocated and old value should be dropped at that point. So, it doesn't make any sense to me this much memory is being used when called from multiple threads.

Can anyone please explain why this code is using this much memory?

Similar code in Java keeps memory ~200mb even with 1000 threads.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    private List<String> data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int n = i;
            new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    f.update();
                    System.gc();
                    System.out.println(n + " updated");
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void update() {
        data = new ArrayList<>(1024 * 1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
            data.add(new String("hello"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (rust 1.37.0) It's consuming < 100MB on my machine even with 2k threads.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev - Really? I have rust 1.39.0-nightly (2019-09-12). Let me install 1.37 and try

Comment: I just tried it. I have 1.37 on Ubuntu. Its going over 3 GB very quickly. Which platform are you on?

Comment: Doesn't each thread have its own arena and allocate the Foo from this arena ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret - I don't know about arenas. So, I am not using those. Or is it something in std?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I'm on MacOS 10.14.6. I've tested on linux and it starts with 150MB for 1 thread and tops at 1G regardless of the number of threads.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev - Weird. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL. I also tried jemallocator explicitly. It then use ~1.1GB

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of memory in use?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I can see the WSL processes in Windows' task manager

Comment: This is most weird: if you comment out the line `println!("{} reloaded", i);`, then the memory consumption stays constant as seen in `top`'s res memory column.

Comment: This seems to be a really, really old [bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19776), which says print statement may leak memory.

Comment: @edwardw For me, it doesn't stay constant even with removing println. However It does take a bit more time to increase in usage. I guess that's probably because previous threads are not letting the other threads to get mutex lock.

Comment: I have run it without println for about 1 minute and memory usage is 4 GB

Comment: Try on Linux run environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2` you binary, this reduce RSS from 3gb to 200mb on my linux amd64 box.

Comment: @fghj so this might very well be related to the allocator giving by default an arena per thread (depending on the OS).

Comment: @fghj OMG yes. that was it.. The memory usage is much better now :) You can add that as answer and I'll accept it. Thank you so much. I have spent so much time on this.

Comment: The same thing happened to java code if you use direct `ByteBuffer`: `public synchronized void update() { ByteBuffer direct = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024 * 1024 * 16); }`. So this particular memory usage pattern does demand the tuning of `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem was in the big numbers of glibc's malloc arenas,
every arena has cache of preallocated memory. The simple way to check it is running binary with `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2`, but final solution depend on usage pattern, there are a lot variables to tune glibc's allocator: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html .

Java virtual machine is also actually affected by malloc's allocator. From my experience some time it is suitable to configure number of arenas to prevent huge memory usage of jvm inside docker.